# get json key of postgres column containing a specific word

Tags: json, node.js, postgresql

I'm trying to select a key from my db and set its value in a json column with postgres keys are finishing with "_alert".

So in my bd I have a column named data as a json and i just want the keys finishing with "_alert" like "ram_alert", "temperatures_alert", "disk_alert", "cpu_alert".

So I need to get the key and the value to compare with the data I have in my backend app to validate if I need to update the value or dont.

How to do this?

I get all the keys doing `select json_object_keys(data) from devices` but how to get the key/value pair.. is there a way to use the "like" expression here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, note that your current query will only work if you have one tuple in your 'devices' table. Try inserting another row and you'll get:

```
ERROR: cannot call json_object_keys on an array
```

If you're certain that you're only ever going to have ONE result from this table, then the following query should give you what you want:

```
SELECT key,value FROM devices,json_each(devices.data) where key ~ '_alert$';
```

I'd still throw something like "LIMIT 1" onto your query to be safe.

Comment: Thanks that worked... I want to get all keys ending with _alert of a device so i added the part "and id = xpto". If I use "limit 1" I just have one element and I want all .